# Can I run a cloud-init environment without using openstack or EC2?

Tags: linux, openstack, cloud-init

I have created an environment with several Linux hosts based on KVM.
I'm using virt-manager to create different VMs and I'm using Linux bridges to create connectivity between VMs in different hosts.

Now, I would like to have an auto-configuration server so that my VMs can auto-configure their name, IP address, run some scripts, etc based on a unique id that each of them has. Is it possible to replicate a sort of cloud-init setup in a non-openstack environment?

I have tried using cloud-init the datasource NoCloud in the following way. First, I have installed cloud-init in the VM and configured cloud.cfg:

```
datasource:
  NoCloud
datasource_list: [ NoCloud ]
disable_ec2_metadata: True
```

Then, I have created a user-data file and meta-data file with the following content:

user-data:

```
#cloud-config
hostname: prueba
password: passw0rd
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
```

meta-data:

```
instance-id: iid-local01
local-hostname: prueba
```

Then, I have generated an iso file:

```
genisoimage  -output seed.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock user-data meta-data
```

Finally, I have attached the disk to the VM and started it. This is the relevant part of the XML:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source file='/opt/images/seed.iso'/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
  <alias name='virtio-disk1'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

When the VM starts, it says:

```
2015-05-12 12:12:40,394 - util.py[WARNING]: Getting data from <class 'cloudinit.sources.DataSourceNoCloud.DataSourceNoCloudNet'> failed
 * Stopping Read required files in advance (for other mountpoints)                           [ OK ]
 * Stopping Read required files in advance (for other mountpoints)                           [ OK ]
 * Stopping Read required files in advance (for other mountpoints)                           [ OK ]
2015-05-12 12:12:48,808 - url_helper.py[WARNING]: Calling 'http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id' failed [3/120s]: request error [HTTPConnectionPool(host='169.254.169.254', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 113] No route to host)]
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: Data sources in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg didn't work properly for me. I've run 'dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init' and specified the NoCloud datasource.

The process for generating the image with the user-data and meta-data was also a bit different:

truncate --size 2M init.img
mkfs.vfat -n cidata init.img
mcopy -oi init1.img user-data meta-data ::

Comment: I inserted a new disk and the result in XML libvirt domain descriptor of the VM was like this:

<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
  <source file='/images/init.img'/>
  <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>

Comment: With the upper config, I can make some cloud config commands work properly (setting password and hostname), while others such as runcmd or write_files do not work yet

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to replicate a sort of cloud-init setup in a non-openstack environment?

Sure.

Cloud-init does not require a network metadata service (like that provided by EC2 and OpenStack) in order to operate.  It will happily read configuration information from a local CD-ROM device; see, for example, the "Loggin in to your Atomic machine" section of [this document](http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/quickstart/), which described how to create the necessary filesystem.

This is documented [here](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/datasources.html#no-cloud) in the cloud-init documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to follow the steps. I have edited my question to include all the steps, but I cannot make it work.

Comment: From the docs, it's not clear the configuration in the virtual machine. How should I configure cloud-init in the VM?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  From your answer posted 5/14 it sounds like you were able to get things working.  At this point you may want to open a new question...

Comment: I configured /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg file in the VM, but it didn't work.
I ran "dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init' and specified the NoCloud datasource, and it partially worked." Some keywords work (setting password and hostname). Others do not (e.g. runcmd, write_files).

So is there any configuration missing in the VM? Are there commands that cannot be used in the NoCloud setup?